# I am writing a program to execute first come first service algorithm , it is showing segmentation error

Tags: c, linked-list, cpu-usage

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct pro{
int at;
int cpu;
struct pro *next;
};
struct pro *head=NULL;

int main()
{
 int n,i,t,c;
 struct pro *temp;
 struct pro *newnode;
 printf("/nenter no. of processes=");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
 {
   newnode=((struct pro *)malloc(sizeof(struct pro)));
   printf("/n enter arrival time=");
   scanf("%d",&t);
   newnode->at=t;
   printf("/n enter cpu burst time=");
   scanf("%d",&c);
   newnode->cpu=c;
   newnode->next=NULL;
   if (head==NULL)
   {`
     head=newnode;
   }
   else
    {temp=head;:
     while(temp!=NULL)
     {
       temp=temp->next;
      }
     newnode=temp->next;
    }
 }
  temp=head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
     printf("\narrival time =%d",temp->at);
     printf("\ncpu birst time=%d",temp->cpu);
   }
 return 0;
}

~
```

I am writing a program to enter and display first come first serve algorithm details , but it seems that program is getting stuck here only before I come to calculation part.
It is showing error code dumped, what am I doing wrong here?

~
~

Comment: Grab a debugger and run the code line by line to see what’s happening. Hint: what’s your loop condition for `temp` when adding a node?

Comment: `newnode=temp->next;` is a error, you are accessing `NULL` pointer

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet which is part of your code, is traversing till the end linked list and trying to access `temp` which is `NULL` and trying to do `(NULL)->next`

```
   while(temp!=NULL)
    {
       temp=temp->next;
     }
     newnode=temp->next;
```

what you need to do is find the last node to append the newnode.Something like this,

```
   while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
       temp=temp->next;
     }
     temp->next=newnode; //newly created node is appended at the end of the list.
```

And Print is an infinite loop as `temp` is unaltered in the loop which supposed to be ,

```
while(temp!=NULL)
   {
     //
     temp = temp->next;
   }
```